# Error missing vendor: Deploying Laravel app to Cloud Foundry

Tags: php, laravel, cloud-foundry

I deployed my app to cloud foundry and bind ClearDB to it for the database. but when I click on the link it shows:

> Missing vendor files try running "composer install" or use the
>   Wizard installer.

Do you have any idea, what is the problem?

Comment: You need to run `composer install`, like it says

Comment: I did it in my machine. But I don't know how to run it in Cloud Foundry

Comment: SSH into your server and run it

Comment: I did it in my server and push app again to cloud foundry but I receive the same error

Comment: You need to include the full output from `cf push`.  That will show us what the build pack is doing when it's staging your application.  Normally the build pack would run `composer` for you (this saves you the trouble of uploading all of your dependencies, although it doesn't hurt anything if you do upload your dependencies).  The fact that the app is complaining about missing dependencies, probably means either `composer` isn't running or files are not where your application expects them.  If you have your app or a sample app online (maybe Github), a link to it would be helpful as well.